# Extracting things I want out of an array?

Tags: php, yaml

I had a yaml file that I needed parsed into an array and I got that done. Now this array is huge. I only want a couple values...

X1, Y1, X2, Y2, owner, that's all I would like. If I can get them to be spit out into arrays nicely it would mean the world to me. (The owner must be the owner related to those X1, y1, x2, y2 values...

(They are are all related to each other) There are many x1,y1 in the array but they all come under headings... etc I don't know how to get them all...

Here is a look at what the array spits out... (Shortened because of filesize limit)
http://pastebin.com/PyH18mZv

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Parse YAML you can use various available PHP parsers. i parsed your YAML by using [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and output the string in JSON. At The end required array values  can be  accessed by decoding the JSON.

*
please note i cut the string short just for example purpose
*

```
$arr='{
"Residences": {
"WorkArea": {"BlackList": {"Type": "BLACKLIST", "ItemList": []}, 
  "EnterMessage": "Welcome %player to %residence, owned by %owner.", 
  "Areas": {
    "main": {
      "Y1": 217, 
      "X1": -6301, 
      "X2": -6306, 
      "Y2": 205, 
      "Z1": 3001, 
      "Z2": 2981
    }
  }, 
  "Permissions": {"Owner": "cal9897","World": "VivaWorld"}
}, 
"caylyn55": {
  "BlackList": {
    "Type": "BLACKLIST", 
    "ItemList": []
  }, 
  "EnterMessage": "Welcome %player to %residence, owned by %owner.", 
  "StoredMoney": 0, 
  "IgnoreList": {
    "Type": "IGNORELIST", 
    "ItemList": []
  }, 
  "LeaveMessage": "Now leaving %residence.", 
  "Subzones": {}, 
  "Areas": {
    "main": {
      "Y1": 67, 
      "X1": 1220, 
      "X2": 1210, 
      "Y2": 64, 
      "Z1": 369, 
      "Z2": 360
    }
  }, 
  "Permissions": {
    "Owner": "caylyn55",
    "PlayerFlags": {}, 
    "GroupFlags": {}, 
    "World": "VivaWorld"
  }
}
}, 
 "Version": 1, 
 "Seed": 1337068141
  }';
```

Decode JSON

```
$a= json_decode($arr,true);
```

First  Area Value get through

```
$a['Residences']['WorkArea']['Areas']['main']['Y1'];
```

and Second Area  value

```
$a['Residences']['caylyn55']['Areas']['main']['Y1'];
```

if ['WorkArea'] AND ['caylyn55'] dynamic you can use this code

```
$b=array_values($a);
foreach($b as $values)
{
if(is_array($values)) {

    foreach(array_keys($values) as $c){

     echo  $a['Residences'][$c]['Areas']['main']['Y1'];

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is I have about 500-800 things which need to be parsed...
$a['Residences']['THIS PART']['Areas']['main']['Y1'];  The part which says THIS PART, is there a way to automate that? With some kind of look, because I'd have to do it for about 500 of them.

Comment: if [This part] is dynamic? then every time you have to know it. if it is already known to you may can save all [THIS PART] in array/database to iterate through parsed YAML.

Comment: It's 100% dynamic, it's from user input so it can be anything :(

Comment: please see the edit, it's just an idea you can use to catch array Keys and values;

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the complete reference to the data you're trying to ouput.

Example: `echo $data['Residences']['WorkArea']['Permissions']['Owner'];`

Comment: can we do away with complete YAML parsing?

Comment: Well I have the yaml file. I need some way for php to read it so I can take suggestions on that? Here is how it would look.... http://pastebin.com/t702t0x9 Would it maybe be a good idea to just have it treat it like a text file? Look for x1,y1 and grab the string w/e after it and then the owner then the next x1,y1 etc

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$extracted = array_map(function ($residence) {
    $r = $residence['Areas']['main'];
    $r['owner'] = $residence['Permissions']['Owner'];
    return $r;
}, $data['Residences']);
```

Comment: $data is parsed yaml array

Comment: The error I am getting is, Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\yaml-load.php on line 20

Comment: Argument #2 should be an array described in pastebin http://pastebin.com/PyH18mZv check its keys and adjust given code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow. I've never done anything with array_maps.

Comment: It is very helpful when dealing with arrays. Checkout its docs and examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php